# How to configure Visual Studio Code and tslint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

In 0.3.0, I'm seeing intellisense for typescript. However, I was also expecting to see some tslinting as I have a tslint.json. Does VSC support linting natively or do I just need to lean on gulp?

If the latter, is it configurable to run as files are changed or does it need to be a manual task that is launched explicitly.

Comment: Based on the [web page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages) they say there is support for linting for TypeScript and C#

Comment: Sami, what am I missing? I see "Intelliense, Linting, outling for CSS, HTML, Javascript, JSON, Less and Sass" only - right below "refactoring, find all references for C#, Typescript". No linting for c#/ts and I'm not seeing it applying my tslint.json rules in the IDE, so I'm assuming it isn't wired up yet. But, wanted to see if I missed a toggle somewhere.

Comment: "No intent to fix" https://code.visualstudio.com/issues/Detail/16540
Suggest we lean on a task https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a linting task to your gulpfile like below. Or even a watcher task. Notice I just use TypeScript, not gulp plug in nor tslint, though they are fine too.

```
gulp.task('ts-watcher', function() {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.ts', ['ts-compile']);
});

gulp.task('ts-compile', function(done) {    
    runTSC('src/client', done);
});

function runTSC(directory, done) {
    var tscjs = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc.js');
    var childProcess = cp.spawn('node', [tscjs, '-p', directory], { cwd: process.cwd() });
    childProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        // Code will read the output
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
    childProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        // Code will read the output
        console.log(data.toString());
    });
    childProcess.on('close', function () {
        done();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks John.  I'm using a watcher now that uses gulp-notify. I was hoping for tighter integration - inline notification, etc. I imagine it is coming.

Comment: I agree. The new WebStorm 11 now has tight integration of TSX with in-line linting. I have gone back and forth between VSC and WS, but am currently sticking with Webstorm until VSC has inline notification.

Comment: I actually dont use any of these. VS Code shows TypeScript issue in the editor without having any of these tasks. What additional things are you wanting? Im curious.

Comment: Getting on this a bit late, but I think @digger69 was asking about tslint annotations in the editor. I personally like the idea of VS Code, but the lack of tslint annotations is preventing me from moving away from sublime.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg There's some way now to get TsLint analyze in VSCode "Problems" view. Linking tslint report with a problem analyzer. Tested it here: http://michael.laffargue.fr/blog/2016/09/16/vscode-make-vscode-tslint-analyze-multiple-files-project/ and it works quite well

Answer (score 34):

## Short answer

> Does VSC support linting natively or do I just need to lean on gulp?

Yes. VS Code supports linting with the [TSLint extension.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) There is no need for gulp.

## Steps to integrate TSLint into VS Code

**First**, install prerequisites: TSLint and TypeScript.

```
npm install -g tslint typescript
```

**Second**, add a `tslint.json` file to your project root. You can do this with `tslint --init`, which gives you nice defaults. Alternatively, create the file and use this minimal config, which inherits [recommended rules.](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/configs/recommended.ts)

```
// tslint.json 
{
  "extends": "tslint:recommended",
  "rules": {}
}
```

**Third**, install the TSLint extension for VS Code.

1. Open VS Code in your project's root.
2. Open the command palette <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
3. `ext install tslint`.
4. Choose Install, then choose Enable, finally restart VS Code.

**Fourth**, enjoy your integrated TS Lint.

[image: TSLint in action in VS Code.]

Comment: I would also add that if using a custom tsconfig.json file try to run it in the console (i.e. tslint **/*.ts) to make sure that it is a valid file otherwise it won't run in VSCode.

Comment: Note that this will only show opened file problems. To get the full list in the "Problems" view, you'll need some more steps I wrote there : http://michael.laffargue.fr/blog/2016/09/16/vscode-make-vscode-tslint-analyze-multiple-files-project/